# Difference between VOIP and IP Telephony

Tags: router, voip, telephony, voice

I am studying CCNA, and in the curriculum I found something like following... ↓↓↓

> VoIP
>
> When introducing VoIP to a network that uses traditional telephones,
>   it is important to remember that VoIP uses voice-enabled routers.
>   These routers convert analog voice from traditional telephone signals
>   into IP packets.
>
> Once converted into IP packets, the router sends those packets between
>   corresponding locations. Voice-enabled routers must be added to the
>   design.
>
> IP Telephony
>
> In IP telephony, the IP phone itself performs voice-to-IP conversion.
>   Voice-enabled routers are not required within the enterprise network.
>   IP phones can use Cisco Unified Communications Manager as a server for
>   call control and signaling. The stadium network requirements include
>   IP telephony.

It says, VOIP does need Voice-Enabled routers, but IP Telephony doesn't need Voice-Enabled routers but CUCM? So I can't understand the difference. So if we use Cisco CUCM, don't we have to use a voice-enabled router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would view it the other way around:  The first difference is in the handset or the "phone" itself.  Is the handset designed specifically for IP telephony?  If not, then you need voice-enabled routers.

Otherwise, you need handsets and routers which are compatible with one another.

POTS = plain old telephone system.  If you take an old phone off of POTS and want to use it in an IP network, then you need voice-enabled routers.

Answer (score 1):

This is, of course, BS. Voice over IP is general term referring to everything from Skype to SIP. Indeed, IP Telephony, although probably a marketing term by Cisco, is more of a synonym.

Answer (score -1):

many companies are using an IP phone system called IP PBX.IP telephones replace the simple phone system in offices.IP phone system uses IP technology for a private data network for a single location or private network.
VOIP system used for public internet to carry voice traffic. when public internet is used you don't have control over the quality of the internet. it is more likely that voice quality over the Internet.

Comment: Your answer seems to be cut short. "it is more likely that voice quality over the Internet..." is what?